# Sending membership renewal / expired reminders is not working

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

All,

I've read the similar questions to this and that hasn't given me any solution yet.

CiviCRM currently 5.58.1, WordPress 6.2. We've had this website up for a bit over a year now so we just started running into having annual memberships require renewing. Memberships were not given the auto renew option at all because of a prior bug that broke payment processing, but thankfully that has since been resolved so I re-enabled auto-renew as an optional thing, so the membership scheduled reminder UI at least gives me something now.

I also just enabled the 'Update Membership Statuses' job, which I thought I did before but clearly didn't. That at least makes the New members Current, and the two members who are past their end date who haven't manually gone to renew their membership are now status of Grace.

Other schedule reminders work just fine (e.g. for events), so that mechanism is working.

I'm trying to set up three distinct scheduled reminders:

One for Membership Renewal reminders
Entity Membership, types selected, Renewal Reminder (non-auto-renew memberships only)
Trigger date 7 days before membership end date.
Record activity for automated email checked
Was going to try repetition every 3 days until 1 hour before membership end date, but currently do not have repeat enabled to just get this to work.
Effective start date was last beginning of last month.
From name and email entered, checked Scheduled Reminder active.
Filled out email template etc.
(Although I'll have to look more closely at how to use tokens, as some like membership.end_date seem to be just for filling that value into the email, but others like membership.membership_type_id:label and contribution.contribution_page_id:label seem to either be also to fill in the value (membership type) or require you to specify which e.g. contribution page you want. Will work on that once I see some emails being sent...)

One for auto-renewal reminder:
Entity Membership, types selected, for Auto-renew Memberships Only
trigger 7 days before membership end date
Record activity for automated email checked
No repeat
From name, email, set
Scheduled Reminder Active checkbox set
Email template created

And finally, one for Expired membership
Entity Membership, type selected, Reminder for Both for auto renew options
Trigger 1 hour after membership end date
Record activity for automated email checked
Effective start date beginning of this month
From name, email, etc. etc. all set like above (different template of course)

Scheduled jobs log says everything's being processed, but no emails are being sent.

Does the membership Status have to be Expired? As in, will this be sent to Grace member status folks, even though the end date is past? I don't see anything about membership status in the reminder configuration, so am assuming it doesn't matter here.

Do these not trigger unless the condition (e.g. 7 days before) is exactly met, which would make it hard to catch folks who slipped through the cracks already?

Any other ideas as to what I'm not doing right?

Thanks.

Michael

Answer (score 2):

Once again, just asking the question by writing it down led me to try more things. The culprit seems to have been me not understanding those tokens; once I fixed that after getting a fatal error message and log file, emails were sent. And it does catch any member who should have gotten a notification at, e.g., T-7 days before membership end, so the trigger date does not have to be exactly as specified.